# How to change ID to product name in URL - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

How can I replace ID with actual product name in the URL. For example instead of:

```
www.myapp.com/product/421156
```

or in general (from routes file)

```
Route::get('/product/{productID}');
```

to

```
www.myapp.com/product/sony-playstation-4
```

Of course, 421156 is an ID of Sony PS4.

Comment: What happens if you hit `www.myapp.com/product/sony-playstation-4` ? The thing you have to modify is how you will manipulate the `{productID}` .  It could be an integer or a string. If you send it to a controller and specific function you could get the post with that slug/title `{productID}`

Answer (score 3):

You should use slugs. For example, you may build URL with something like this:

```
{{ route('route-name', 'sony-playstation-4') }}
```

And then search data by slug, instead of using ID:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

To generate a slug from a product name, you can use [`str_slug()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-str-slug) helper or use one of many packages.

Comment: You don't even need to manually look for the slug using `::where` if you customize your route key. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing ( section Customizing The Key Name)

Comment: But I have about million products. I cannot define the route name for each of them :/ . I thought if there is a way to use the product name instead of ID

Comment: @harunB10 you need to define just one route for all product.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin where do I define this `{{ route('route-name', 'sony-playstation-4') }}` routes/web.php ? ... Is it the equivalent of `Route::get()` ?

Comment: No, it's not. `route()` helper simply creates URL based on route name. You should define route in the `web.php` routes file.